# How to write unique ID(s) of polygons in layer A intersecting polygons in layer B to field in layer B?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, database, census, tiger

I'm working in ArcGIS 10.1. Suppose that I have two polygon layers, **A** and **B**.

Polygons in layer **B** can have one of a few relationships to those in layer **A**:

1. They may be completely contained by polygons in layer **A**
2. They may intersect (be shared by) multiple polygons in layer **A**
3. They may be completely contained *but coextensive with* those in layer **A**

I know of a number of ways to visually identify, or select for, these relationships, but I'm wondering if anyone has some idea of how I could write, to the attribute table of **B**, values from the unique ID of layer **A** based on these relationships?

FWIW, I'm working with the relationships among counties, county subdivisions, and places in the TIGER hierarchy -- i.e., where **A** = County Subdivisions and **B** = Places, and in turn where **A** = Counties and **B** = County Subdivisions.  It's possible that I'm neglecting some of the potential relationships between A and B in the way I've laid out the list above.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the spatial join geo-processing tool to create separate datasets for each spatial relation. The trick here is not to ignore the drop down "Join Operation" and select the one to many option.